# Converting .htaccess to nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I tried to convert following .htaccess rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[^.]+|[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?type=%1&b=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}  [L]
```

with the nginx .htaccess converter I end up with this:

```
if ($http_host ~ "^www\.domain\.com$"){
    set $rule_0 1;
}

if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://domain.bg/$1 permanent;
}

if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_1 1$rule_1;
}

if ($http_host ~* "^([^.]+\.[^.]+|[^.]+)\.domain\.com$"){
    set $rule_1 2$rule_1;
    set $bref_1_0 $1;
}

if ($rule_1 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?type=${bref_1_0}&b=$1&$args last;
}
```

but it is not working. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Love how those generators generate weird long un-understandable stuff,
The first part is a www to non-www redirect, which is easy

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 example.com;
}
```

I'm not sure about this part but you can try

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<subs>[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+)?)\.example\.com;
    rewrite ^ /index.php?type=%1&b=$subs&$args last;
}
```

Hope it works